# how to set a method dependency injection in c# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, methods, dependency-injection

Hello I'm trying to implement a logger that enters the log into a file. The path to the file is stored in my appSettings.json. With Model classes I made a reference to my appSettings.json. Here is the LogWriter.cs

```
    public class LogWriter
    {
        public void WriteLog(string message, IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
        {
            AppSettings _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(_appSettings.LogFilePath))
            {
                writer.Write("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") +"] " + message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to inject the appSettings dependency via the WriteLog method so that I can call the method without creating an instance of the LogWriter class. To create the dependency I show you my program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

var appSettings = new AppSettings();
builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(appSettings);

//Add services to the container.
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IMessageService, MessageService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<LogWriter>();// DI for LogWriter

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MailContext>(
    o => o.UseNpgsql(appSettings.ConnectionStrings.MailDb)
    );

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

When I call the method with `LogWriter.WriteLog("Text for testing")`, I get an error that one argument is missing. For example in my controller.

```
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MessageController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMessageService _mailService;

        public MessageController(IMessageService mailServiceCustom )
        {
            _mailService = mailServiceCustom;
            LogWriter.WriteLog("Construktor wird ausgeführt");

        }
...
```

Comment: Have a look at the already existing [ILogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) interface. You should start implementing from there. As it then more clean to not have a concrete Logger class but a logger that is itself injectable.

Comment: By the way the injection thing works on constructors not on methods. You can't just leaves parameters away and hope that somehow missing parameters get injected.

Comment: That's not entirely true. I've read that there are 3 ways to inject dependency sites. 1. via constructor, 2. via methods and 3. property injection
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/3-types-dependency-injection-mohammad-ramezani#:~:text=There%20are%20three%20types%20of,method%20injection%2C%20and%20property%20injection.

Comment: You are obviously coding something in Asp.Net and for the DI Framework there its correct. It does Constructor injection. There are ways for property injection but method injection would need language support and in standard c# its just not there.

Comment: There are no static methods in your logging class

Comment: Yes, there are three basic ways how dependencies can be supplied to a class. Concerning method injection however, the referenced (linkedin) article already states that: "In both cases, it’s up to the caller to decide what implementation to pass to the method." So it's not up to the DI Container but rather the *caller* to inject the dependency. That's why DI Containers, such as Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (MS.DI), typically do not support method injection. And MS.DI solely supports Constructor Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as written would require the `WriteLog` method to be static which is probably not what you want.

The usual way to manage DI in .NET is via constructor injection, often via an interface to separate *what* is being done from *how* it is being done.

The simplest fix is for your `LogWriter` class to take an `IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings` as a parameter in its constructor instead of its `WriteLog` method and store it in a `private readonly` variable, and then for your `MessageController` class to take a `LogWriter` in *its* constructor.

That said, as mentioned in the comments, there are well known `ILogger` and `ILogger<T>` interfaces plus numerous logging solutions implementing these interfaces, so you would likely be better off not reinventing the wheel